# Site does not contain the appropriate root file

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

I'm trying to create a sample mobile application by following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EprKIkCjKhQ)  video tutorial . I already installed successfully the android SDK. But I'm always getting an error message every time I try to build and emulate my sample site in Dreamweaver cs5.5

```
Your site does not contain the appropriate root file. 
Please contains a file named "index.html" and try again.
```

It is my first time to create a mobile application for android. Can you help me with my problem.

Comment: Did you try to follow the advice from the error message?

Comment: yes, i have a index.html file